# Command line error in function call

Tags: matlab

I am working on a GA code in MATLAB. When I execute the following syntax in the command window

```
 function[opt,fopt,histf]=ga(n,fitnessfct,decodefct,selectfct,stopeval)
```

I get the following error

> Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.

Comment: If you have a function called `ga`, call it without `function` from the command line: `[opt,fopt,histf]=ga(n,fitnessfct,decodefct,selectfct,stopeval)`

Answer (score 2):

You must define your function in another M-file named by `ga`.

**1-** Create a new script, M-file where you can you use "Ctrl+N"

**2-** Declare your function writing:

```
function [opt, fopt, histf] = ga(n, fitnessfct, decodefct, selectfct, stopeval)
   % // function statements
end
```

**3-** Save the function file and name it as `ga`

**4-** Make sure setting the path of current directory to your working directory.

That is it..